# Opening web browser on linux virtual machine

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, command, virtual-machine, git-bash

I have created a virtual linux machine from amazon web services... the terminal that opens up is the gitbash prompt. I'm trying to open any web browser but I couldnt find a command to do so. I have tried xdg-open, start and several other commands that I came across but they wouldnt work. Please assist me!

Answer (score 0):

The text based lynx is usually installed by default. Otherwise if X-windows is installed and configured, the shell command "startx" will start a GUI session.

But gitbash is tiny and is void of most packages to reduce space...